# Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActiveCellFont).Show Argument "9" (Underline)

Tags: excel, vba, dialog

I have a Userform that users will work with to change around some settings for a future tool I am working on. One thing they can provide input on is the default font for some milestone text boxes that will be generated by future code. The area where they can see the current font settings and the button to open up and utilize Excel's default Dialogs(xlDialogActiveCellFont) to select the font, font size, and whatever else.

[Userform for updating a default font style for future code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmsuQ.png)

One thing I am running problems into is Arg9 ("Underline") in Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActiveCellFont).Show(...); Microsoft does not tell you what variable type this is (single, integer, string, etc.), and I can't seem to find any input that it likes.

As ActiveCell.Font.Underline is a "Long" variable type, I assume Arg9 wants it in the same format, which is what the private function "GetData_MSMFontUnderline" provides that translates the underline style "name" with its associated style number. So say the textbox in the Userform is "None", GetData_MSMFontUnderline will return -4142 or xlUnderlineStyleNone as a Long variable type. I tried entering strings (e.g. "None" or "-4142") and the Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActiveCellFont).Show(...) doesn't like it.

I get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Unable to get the Show property of the Dialog Class

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActiveCellFont)
        If .Show(Arg1:=Me.Txt_MSMFontName.Value, Arg3:=Int(Me.Txt_MSMFontSize.Value), Arg9:=GetData_MSMFontUnderline(Me.Txt_MSMFontUnderline, FALSE)) = True Then
            Me.Txt_MSMFontName.Value = .Application.ActiveCell.Font.Name
            Me.Txt_MSMFontSize = .Application.ActiveCell.Font.Size
            Me.ChkBox_MSMFontBold.Value = .Application.ActiveCell.Font.Bold
            Me.ChkBox_MSMFontItalic.Value = .Application.ActiveCell.Font.Italic
            Me.Txt_MSMFontUnderline = GetData_MSMFontUnderline(.Application.ActiveCell.Font.Underline, True)
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Function GetData_MSMFontUnderline(ValIn As Variant, Optional Bln_ValIsNumber As Boolean) As Variant

    Dim arr(1 To 2, 1 To 5) As Variant
        
        arr(1, 1) = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        arr(2, 1) = "None"
        arr(1, 2) = xlUnderlineStyleDouble
        arr(2, 2) = "Double"
        arr(1, 3) = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        arr(2, 3) = "Single"
        arr(1, 4) = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        arr(2, 4) = "Single Accounting"
        arr(1, 5) = xlUnderlineStyleDoubleAccounting
        arr(2, 5) = "Double Accounting"

    Dim i As Long
    
    On Error GoTo ExitFunc
        If Bln_ValIsNumber Then
            
            For i = 1 To 5
                If arr(1, i) = ValIn Then
                    GetData_MSMFontUnderline = arr(2, i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

        Else
        
            For i = 1 To 5
                If arr(2, i) = ValIn Then
                    GetData_MSMFontUnderline = arr(1, i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            
        End If
        
ExitFunc:

End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated! maybe I am overlooking something!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `Arg9` accepts `1` through `5`, corresponding to the following inputs:

```
1: None
2: Single
3: Double
4: Single Accounting
5: Double Accounting
```

Comment: So I put in Arg9:=xlUnderlineStyleNone and get the same runtime error. Also tried Arg9:=None, Arg9:="None", Arg9:=-4142. It is rather puzzling...only time it opens is when I keep Arg9 out of the .Show(...) command, but this defeats the purpose unfortunately.

Comment: You need `Arg9:=1`, `Arg9:=2`, etc.

Comment: Oh....well there we go!

Comment: I doubt this is documented anywhere ... found by trial and error.

Comment: No all the dialog options have descriptions of the arguments, but I couldn't for the life of me find details about the arguments themselves. Black box; thanks for the help!